# How do I remove a class from a bunch of views?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here is my template:

```
<table id="locationDataTable" class="large-data-table" cellspacing='0' border='0'>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        {{view App.LocationDataTable type='kwh'}}
      </th>
      <th>
        {{view App.LocationDataTable type='btu'}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my view JS:

```
App.LocationDataTable = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  classNames: ['carrot'],
  classNameBindings: ['direction', 'isActive:active'],
  direction: 'down',
  isActive: false,

  click: function(){

    // remove active class from all #locationDataTable span

    this.set('isActive', true);  // set active only on this one

    var type = this.get('type');
    this.get('controller').set('sortProperties', [type]);

    if (this.get('direction') === 'up') {
      this.set('direction', 'down');
      this.get('controller').set('sortAscending', true);
    } else {
      this.set('direction', 'up');
      this.get('controller').set('sortAscending', false);
    }
  }
});
```

I dont know if I am doing this in the best way... i tried using the action helper like `{{action 'sortTable'}}` before and had a similar issue... i could have different view js for each element, but still, how will i remove the active class from all of them?

Let me know if I didn't explain myself well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have some sort of `ArrayController` managing your list of objects.  Maybe something like `App.LocationsController`.  Something like this should work.

```
App.LocationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectNone : function(){
    this.get('content').forEach(function(location){
      location.set('isActive',false); 
    });
  }
});

App.LocationDataTableController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs : ['locations']
});

App.LocationDataTable = Ember.View.extend({
  // your other stuff here...
  click: function(){

    // remove active class from all #locationDataTable span
    this.get('controller.controllers.locations').selectNone();

    this.set('isActive', true);  // set active only on this one

    // your other stuff here...
  }
});
```